# IOS Facebook SSO: isSessionValid() returns false when login in via facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5

I am developing an IOS5.1 app using Objective C. I have implemented facebook SSO for native IOS app http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/authentication/ for my application login feature.

The flow of my app starts from a loginViewController. When user cicks the login button in my app, the app will check isSessionValid(). If the method returns true, user will be directed to next page. During simulation on provisioned phone, my current app is able to direct me to either mobile safari web browser (if there's no facebook app) or facebook app. isSessionValid() returns true and directs me to the next view page when I log in via safari web browser. However, if there's a facebook app in the provisioned Iphone, facebook app pops out when i click the login button in my application. The facebook app shows a white page with an activity indicator "Loading..." then it directs me back to my application. When I click on the login button again, facebook app pops up again. This becomes an endless loop. I am unable to go to next page when i try to login via facebook app on the provisioned iphone.

Here is my code:

In AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSMutableDictionary *userPermissions;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) LoginViewController *loginvc;
```

In AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    self.loginvc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = loginvc;

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"facebookID" andDelegate:self.loginvc];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    // Initialize user permissions
    userPermissions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

In LoginViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)loginViaFacebook:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (![[delegate facebook] isSessionValid]) {
        [[delegate facebook] authorize:permissions];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signup" sender:self];
    }
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[[delegate facebook] accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[[delegate facebook] expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

... all neccessary facebook protocols are implemented in LoginViewController.m.

I am using storyBoard. And the starting ViewController used in the storyboard is LoginViewController.
I am sure when facebook sso works when login via mobile safari web browser BUT NOT via facebook app.

Hope someone knows the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According SSO implementation on Facebook Documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso, you have to implement this on AppDelegate.h delegates:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>
```

Hope this could help.